# Excel/VBA: Dialog box, select & delete rows>5, multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

Code below works good for deleting rows on the active worksheet, but I would love to have a couple of changes. I am not good at VBA, this code is a sample from another place. I would like two different codes, one for the current worksheet and one for multiple worksheets.

1. I don't want to be able to delete rows 1-5 for this code. Some kind of dialog box that says: "You can only delete row "6" or below".

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Sub DeleteMe()
       Dim Ret As Range, Cl As Range

       On Error Resume Next
       Set Ret = Application.InputBox("Mark rows to be deleted", "Delete rows", Type:=8)
       On Error GoTo 0

       ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="password"

       If Not Ret Is Nothing Then Ret.EntireRow.Delete

       ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="password"
   End Sub
   ```
2. Another similar code as above (delete row 6 or higher) with dialog box and selection, but when I select rows in worksheet A, the same rows in worksheet B and C are also deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below codefor your requrement. 
First code for Activesheet  and second code for multiple sheets

```
Sub aActivesSheet()
Dim Rownum As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Dim RngA As Range

Dim lastrow As Long

Set ws = ActiveSheet
 lastrow = ws.UsedRange.Rows(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

Rownum = Application.InputBox("Enter row number")

ws.Rows(Rownum & ":" & lastrow).Delete



End Sub


Sub MultipleSheeetss()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsa, wsb, wsc As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Set wsa = wb.Worksheets("SheetA")
Set wsb = wb.Worksheets("SheetB")
Set wsc = wb.Worksheets("SheetC")

Dim Rownum As Variant

Rownum = Application.InputBox("Enter row number and above to be deleted")



For i = 1 To Rownum

wsa.Rows(i).ClearContents
wsb.Rows(i).ClearContents
wsc.Rows(i).ClearContents

'or use delete

'wsa.Rows(i).delete


Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

slightly different to what you have now but it does work

```
Sub DeleteMe()
Dim Ret1 As Long
Dim Ret2 As Long
Dim i As Long

On Error Resume Next
Ret1 = Application.InputBox("Start Row to be Deleted?", "Start Row")
Ret2 = Application.InputBox("End Row to be Deleted?", "End Row")
On Error GoTo 0

If Ret1 > Ret2 Then
MsgBox "Start Row must be lower than End Row"

Else
    If Ret1 > 5 Then
        For i = Ret1 To Ret2
        Rows(Ret1).EntireRow.Delete
        Next i

    ElseIf Ret1 <= 5 Then
    MsgBox "Only Rows 6 and above can be deleted"

    End If

End If

End Sub
```

this asks for a start row and end row rather than just selecting a range

to delete the same rows on different sheets add this in

```
For i = Ret1 To Ret2
        Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(Ret1).EntireRow.Delete
        Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(Ret1).EntireRow.Delete
        Sheets("Sheet3").Rows(Ret1).EntireRow.Delete
Next i
```